# .NET: Load two version of the same DLL

Tags: .net, appdomain

I need to load two versions of the same DLL in order to compare their outputs. I assume that I can use AppDomains for this, but I need some guidence.

Comment: Does the assembly you want to compare has other references? Is the assembly strong named?

Comment: No, the assemblies don't have strong names.

Comment: No, the assemblies don't have other references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, it was actually a lot easier than I imagined.

```
    m_Assembly1 = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Old Version\Some.dll"))
    m_Assembly2 = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "New Version\Some.dll"))

    Console.WriteLine("Old Version: " & m_Assembly1.GetName.Version.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("New Version: " & m_Assembly2.GetName.Version.ToString)

    m_OldObject = m_Assembly1.CreateInstance("FullClassName")
    m_NewObject = m_Assembly2.CreateInstance("FullClassName")
```

From here on out I used late binding and/or reflection to run my tests.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Activator.CreateInstance() on MSDN.  Code samples within.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224132.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx) is a guide to do that:

```
extern alias oldVer;
extern alias newVer;
```

and when you compile:

```
csc /r:oldVer=Somepath\ClassLibrary.dll /r:newVer=AnotherPath\ClassLibrary.dll program.cs
```

or in Visual Studio change the "aliases" field in the property tab of your project references
[image]

Comment: We had some problem with this approach if ClassLibrary.dll references another assembly, the clr would only resolve the first version of the dependency, the second version dependency was resolved as the first version. We had to subscribe to AppDomain.ResolveAssembly and do some nasty things to overcome this problem.

Comment: My test harness is already written in VB, so of course that would have to be a C#-only feature.