# Loading the same Assembly twice but with different version

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, version, .net-assembly

I have one assembly that is called asm.dll.

This assembly has the version 1.0.0.0 (*set within AssemblyInfo.cs*)

Then I need do do some code modifications in that assembly (still asm.dll), advance the version to 2.0.0.0 and build it again.

Now, I have two files named asm.dll that differ with respect to some code modifications and a their version number.

How do I load these two files during runtime?

**ADDENDUM:**

Right now I am trying the following:

```
var asm1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("dir1\asm.dll");
var asm2 = Assembly.LoadFrom("dir2\asm.dll");

var types1 = asm1.GetTypes();
var types2 = asm2.GetTypes();

Type type1 = types1.First<Type>(t => t.Name.Equals("myClassIWantToInstantiate"));
Type type2 = types2.First<Type>(t => t.Name.Equals("myClassIWantToInstantiate"));

MyObject myObject1 = (MyObject1)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { });
MyObject myObject2 = (MyObject2)Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { });
```

But I get the following behavior:

- the first call to `Activator.CreateInstance(...)` correctly returns the requested instance for `myObject1`
- the second call to `Activator.CreateInstance(...)` returns again `myObject1` instead of `myObject2`
- The code compiles and the program runs without exception or observable problems, except that I do not get `myObject2`

I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016990/net-load-two-version-of-the-same-dll/2023445#2023445) and I think the code I used, is the same, only a bit newer (correct me, if I am wrong).

Comment: Just strong name and GAC them then you can just add references to both. No funky reflection required. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder

Comment: Bit late to the party but I had similar problem, I had to load in 2 instances of the same dll from the same folder (different names), what worked for me was `ObjectHandle` from `Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(string,string)` and then `Unwrap()` to get the object. [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fce0hc8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer, you are using Activator.CreateInstance for both objects - this is using whatever is registered globally.  I believe the types loaded from the specific assemblies will not be enough to do this.

In the answer you linked, the assemblies are loaded using `Assembly.LoadFile` rather than `LoadFrom`, and `CreateInstance` is called on the assembly instance, rather than using the static `Activator.CreateInstance`.  Have you tried this?

```
var asm1 = Assembly.LoadFile("dir1\asm.dll");
var asm2 = Assembly.LoadFile("dir2\asm.dll");

MyObject myObject1 = (MyObject)asm1.CreateInstance("myClassIWantToInstantiate");
MyObject myObject2 = (MyObject)asm2.CreateInstance("myClassIWantToInstantiate");
```

Comment: No, i just checked it. It seems that the problem lies at `var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);` because here the second call still return the same assembly (even though the passed file string is different)

Comment: ... that means that in my code both calls `var asm1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("dir1\asm.dll");` and `var asm2 = Assembly.LoadFrom("dir2\asm.dll");` do return the same assembly.

Comment: The linked answer used Assembly.LoadFile rather than Assembly.LoadFrom - have you tried that?

Comment: In fact, that works! But this seems to introduce another issue because now it seems that I cannot repeat the instantiation of `myObject`. The first call to `asm1.CreateInstance(..)` works, the seconds call works too, but if I do again call `asm1.CreateInstance(..)` I get the following  Exceptions: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`and `A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: The issue in my original post was solved by your comment that suggests to use `LoadFile(string)` rather then `LoadFrom(string)`. If you add this to your answer, I will mark it as answer, because then it would fit my question perfectly.

Comment: Updated answer to include my earlier comment