# Xoml only Workflow activity assembly version

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I re-hosted the workflow designer in a standalone application. Is there a way to force the designer to not include the version of the Assembly containing my custom activities.

What is happening is that my custom activity assembly version changes quite often. Thus, my rehosted designer throw an exception since the version in the xoml is in version A. And now my custom activity assembly is in Version B.

My re-hosted designer compiles with my custom assembly so any changes to the version of my custom assembly will break my workflows. The only way to make it work is to open it in the XML editor and to manually change the version to B. Hope that clears things up.

Basically, I'm wondering when serializing into xml, if it's possible to not include the Version of the custom assembly??? Is this possible ?

Comment: You may need to clarify what you're doing and why its going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps your problem but [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/09/10/versioning-long-running-workfows.aspx) describes how to use multiple versions of an assembly side by side.

Other that that you might decide not to use a strongly named assembly or update the version number so .NET versioning doesn't come into play

Comment: Thanks, but not really looking at runing multiple version of my workflow. The workflows is the same, it's just that the version of the assembly containing my custom activity has change. That's pretty much the only thing that changed.

Comment: Running or designing is pretty much the same thing here. You have a workflow/activity version x but the workflow loader wants to load version y. The easiest option is not to use version numbers in your assembly so the runtime will see the assembly and think its is the same thing. You just have to make sure you don't introduce breaking changes in the public interfaces you use.

Comment: The thing is that I have no choice. I need the version number in my assemblies ....

Comment: That I suggest using a bindingRedirect to redirect .NET to the newer version of the assembly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809262/how-to-programatically-modify-assemblybinding-in-app-config for an example config file.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is not changing the AssemblyVersion but the FileVersion instead. That way the assembly containing your custom activities remains compatible and you are still able to tell the version from the assembly properties.